# Why does `animation-direction: reverse` not work for my CSS keyframe animation?

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to use `animation-direction: reverse` to refactor my CSS keyframe animation. I have a container div when clicked will toggle an "active" class on it via jQuery which triggers the animation (forward or backward depending on the "active" state). The forward and backward animations are exactly the same thing except the keyframes are in the reverse order. I figured that `animation-direction: reverse` would enable me to refactor it by just using one animation and reversing it for the other, but it's not working the way I thought it would.

Link to codepen (without using `animation-direction: reverse`):
https://codepen.io/soultrust/pen/gogKjN

The following markup and CSS (Sass) code snippet is the way it works now without reverse.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

```
$width-height: 100px;
$duration: 1s;
$line-width: 10%;
$animation-distance: $width-height * .45;

@keyframes line-in {
  0% { transform: translateY(-$animation-distance); }
  50% { transform: translateY(0); }
  100% { transform: rotate(-135deg); }
}

@keyframes line-out {
  0% { transform: rotate(-135deg); }
  50% { transform: translateY(0); }
  100% { transform: translateY(-$animation-distance); }
}

.container {
  margin: 10rem auto 0;
  width: $width-height;
  height: $width-height;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;

  &.active {
    .line {
      animation-name: line-in;
      animation-direction: normal;
    }
  }
}

.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: $line-width;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  background-color: orange;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-name: line-out;
  animation-duration: $duration;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

When I change the "active" animation to following, animations in both directions stop working.

```
&.active {
  .line {
    animation-name: line-out;
    animation-direction: reverse;
  }
}
```

I believe it has something to do with using the same animation because if I just set the `animation-direction: reverse` and use `animation-name: line-in`, it correctly plays the line-in animation in reverse.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Very good question. You have already noticed that `animation-direction: reverse;` does work. You where very close to figuring out this css quirkiness all by yourself.

There are some additional rules to take note off.

- When removing/replacing a css animation, the animation will start from 0%,
- When you set `reverse` (while not changing the actual animation), the animation will continue from whatever % it was at.

So when you clicked the element and set the `line-out` animation:

- The animation will start from 0%
- Play in whatever direction you've set.

When only applying a new animation direction:

- The animation continous from whatever percentage it was, eg, 100%.

You can [restart](https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/) the animation with several forms of trickery. you'll see that the animation is being played in reverse when the element is recreated.

```js
var clickFunc =function(e) {    
      //toggle the state
      $(this).toggleClass("active");
      //reset the animatino state by cloning and replacing the element.
      var newone = this.cloneNode(true);
      this.parentNode.replaceChild(newone, this);
      // reapply click handler to the cloned element
      $(newone).click(clickFunc)   
}


$(function() {
  $(".question").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
  });
  
    $(".answer").click(clickFunc);

  $(".restart").click(function() {
    $(".line").each(function() {
      var newone = this.cloneNode(true);
      this.parentNode.replaceChild(newone, this);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
@keyframes line-in {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-45px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
  }
}
@keyframes line-out {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-45px);
  }
}
.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  background-color: orange;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-name: line-in;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.container {
  margin: 1rem auto 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.container.reverse .line {
  animation-name: line-in;
  animation-direction: reverse;
}
.container.active .line {
  animation-name: line-in;
  animation-direction: reverse;
}
.container.active.reverse .line {
  animation-name:line-in;
  animation-direction: normal;
}

.container.out.active .line {
  animation-name: line-out;
  animation-direction: normal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="restart">reset animation state</button><br>
in -out
<div class="container question out">
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>

active reversed
<div class="container question">
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>

<br>

workaround
<div class="container answer reverse">
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

In order to debug this. You can inspect the animation states in the web dev tools of your browser:
[image]

With regards to your refactor:
I would rather have multiple animations in different directions, than doing js tricks in order to restart/reverse an animation.

Depending on how complicated your animation is, you might be better of using css transitions as opposed to animation frames. You would not have to worry about reversing/resetting the animation.