# How to implement CSS animations based on media-query breakpoints being hit?

Tags: css, sass, css-animations

As part of making our websystem responsive to mobile devices, I'm using CSS media queries to alternate between having a header bar and a hamburger menu.

Now I thought it'd be a nice gimmick if it animated between the two layouts when desktop users adjusted the size of their browser window beyond the bounds defined by the media queries. As a proof-of-concept test I've been experimenting with the transition between our large logo and the small one.

My animations.scss file contains these two animations:

```
@mixin ToSmallLogo() {
    background-image: url('../../../../PageAssets/fissmall.png');
    width: 7%;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-name: SwapToSmallLogo;

    @keyframes SwapToSmallLogo {
        0% {
            width: 100%;
            background-image: url('../../../PageAssets/Fis.png');
        }

        100% {
            background-image: url('../../../../PageAssets/fissmall.png');
            width: 7%;
        }
    }
}

@mixin SwapToBigLogo() {
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url('../../../PageAssets/Fis.png');
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-name: SwapToBigLogo;

    @keyframes SwapToBigLogo {
        0% {
            background-image: url('../../../../PageAssets/fissmall.png');
            width: 7%;
            width: 100%;
            background-image: url('../../../PageAssets/Fis.png');
        }

        100% {
            width: 100%;
            background-image: url('../../../PageAssets/Fis.png');
        }
    }
}
```

Then I've got a SCSS file specifically for the media queries, containing:

```
@import '../../Variables/Sizes.scss';
@import '../Animations/animations.scss';

@media screen and (max-width: $bigToSmallFISLogo) {
    #franklin {
        @include ToSmallLogo();
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: $bigToSmallFISLogo){
    #franklin{
        @include SwapToBigLogo();
    }
}
```

While the CSS before application of the media queries is this:

```
#franklin {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url('../../../PageAssets/Fis.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    height: 72px;
}
```

My issue is, while shrinking the screen past the defined size works perfectly, going back up just snaps to the larger image with no animation. I'd thought that the culprit was that I had the image defined in the CSS before application of the media queries, so I removed that part of it; but that just resulted in having no image.

Then while typing this question I had the idea use a media query to determine the direction of the animation, like so:

```
@mixin SwapLogo() {
/*    background-image: url('../../../../PageAssets/fissmall.png');
    width: 7%;*/
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-name: SwapLogo;

    @media screen and (max-width: $bigToSmallFISLogo) {
        animation-direction: normal;
        background-image: url('../../../../PageAssets/fissmall.png');
        width: 7%;
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: $bigToSmallFISLogo) {
        animation-direction: reverse;
        width: 100%;
        background-image: url('../../../PageAssets/Fis.png');
    }

    @keyframes SwapLogo {
        0% {
            width: 100%;
            background-image: url('../../../PageAssets/Fis.png');
        }

        100% {
            background-image: url('../../../../PageAssets/fissmall.png');
            width: 7%;
        }
    }
}
```

That resulted in the animation being ran on page load, but not at the resize.

Is there any way to do what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of experimentation, I've finally sussed it out. Essentially, as Lars pointed out, I'd forgotten to delete a couple of bits; but the solution I ended up with (which seems a bit smoother, as it fades one image into the other) is to have the base CSS as:

```
#franklin {
    display: block;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    height: 72px;
}
```

Then the mixin to apply the animation as follows:

```
@mixin SwapLogo($img, $width, $startIMG, $startWidth, $animationName) {
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-name: $animationName;
    background-image: $img;
    width: $width;

    @keyframes #{$animationName} {
        0% {
            width: $startWidth;
            background-image: $startIMG;
        }

        100% {
            background-image: $img;
            width: $width;
        }
    }
}
```

With the media queries being:

```
@media screen and (max-width: calc($bigToSmallFISLogo + 10px)) { //This overlap of 10px basically allows for the animation to take effect as the other animation is removed. 
    #franklin {
        @include SwapLogo(url('../../../../PageAssets/fissmall.png'), 7%, url('../../../../PageAssets/Fis.png'), 100%, LogoGoSmall);
        margin-top: 13px;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: $bigToSmallFISLogo) {
    #franklin {
        @include SwapLogo(url('../../../../PageAssets/Fis.png'), 100%, url('../../../../PageAssets/fissmall.png'), 7%, LogoGoBig);
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: $minSizeForDesktopMenu) and (min-width: $bigToSmallFISLogo) {
    #franklin {
        margin-top: 26px;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: $minSizeForDesktopMenu) {
    #franklin {
        margin-top: 13px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Option 1 contains some faulty css

You've set the starting to `width: 100%;` on your `SwapToBigLogo`

```
    @keyframes SwapToBigLogo {
        0% {
            background-image: url('../../../../PageAssets/fissmall.png');
            width: 7%;
            width: 100%; <---- culprit
            background-image: url('../../../PageAssets/Fis.png');
        }
```

Essentially, you're animation from `width: 100%` to `width:100%`. If you remove that line, it will probably work.

## Option 2 tricky with reversing

When you reverse an animation, it will not reset iteration count and progress of the animation.
IE if you 'reverse' an animation at 100% finished. it will just apply the 100% finished of the 'reverse'  state.  *not start from 0% reverse and animate to 100% reversed*

see my answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47988435/why-does-animation-direction-reverse-not-work-for-my-css-keyframe-animation/47992656#47992656) if you want to circumvent that

## Alternative, use Transitions instead

If you have no need for complex animations and just want to smoothly transition from one state to another.
**I would prefer to use css transitions.**

```
#franklin {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url('../../../PageAssets/Fis.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    height: 72px;
    transition: width 2s ease-in; // <--- this will animate when the media query kicks in.
}


@media screen and (max-width: $bigToSmallFISLogo) {
    #franklin {
       background-image: url('../../../../PageAssets/fissmall.png');
       width: 7%; 
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: $bigToSmallFISLogo){
    #franklin{
         width: 100%;
         background-image: url('../../../PageAssets/Fis.png');
    }
}
```

## Bonus

You can apply transitions to a * selector. (I would not recommend that for production grade websites, but it's fun to toy with.) It will cause everything to smoothly transition when your media query changes widths/layouts.

```css
* {
  transition: all 2s;
}

body {
  background-color: red;
  color: black;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.logo {
  width: 200px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding:20px;
}


/* On screens that are 992px wide or less, the background color is blue */

@media screen and (max-width: 630px) {
  body {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .logo {
    width: 100px;
    border: 3px solid orange;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding:10px;
  }
}


/* On screens that are 600px wide or less, the background color is olive */

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  body {
    background-color: lime;
    color: white;
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  .logo {
    width: 50px;
    border: 1px solid indigo;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding:2px;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Resize window</h1>
<p>
  <img class="logo" src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="logo">
</p>
```